# I am having problems to use EXISTS or PERFORM in a function to find out whether a row exists or not

Tags: postgresql

I found several examples with EXISTS and PERFORM, but none worked for what I want to do. Following is what I have and it works, returning `{"success" : true, "balance" : "500.00"}`
 :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (id text, balance text);
INSERT INTO accounts(id, balance) VALUES ('123', '500.00');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get_balance(id text)
RETURNS json AS
$$
SELECT json_build_object('success', true, 'balance', balance)
FROM
    (
        SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE id = id
    ) _;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;

SELECT pg_temp.get_balance('123');
```

Of course, sometimes an account - e.g. `SELECT pg_temp.get_balance('456');` - doesn't exist. Then I'd like to get sth. like `{"success" : false}`. Can somebody perhaps give me hint how this needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Using one small trick:

```
with accounts (id, balance) as (values(123, 500.00))
select * from (select) as dummy left join accounts on (id = 123);
```

It allows to return at least one row even if there is no data in the right hand table. Note that the filtering condition should be in the `join on` part instead of the `where` clause.

Then you can to convert the result to `JSON`:

```
with accounts (id, balance) as (values(123, 500.00))
select json_build_object('success', id is not null, 'balance', balance)
from (select) as dummy left join accounts on (id = 123);
```

You can to use `case` statement if you do not want to have "balance" key if requested account not exists:

```
with accounts (id, balance) as (values(123, 500.00))
select
    case
        when id is null then json_build_object('success', false)
        else json_build_object('success', true, 'balance', balance)
    end
from (select) as dummy left join accounts on (id = 456);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get_balance(_id text)
RETURNS json AS
$$
SELECT json_build_object('success', _.balance IS NULL, 'balance', balance)
FROM (SELECT 1) s
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE id = _id) _ ON TRUE;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=06e3529da306ff90cd2326697c6d3ac7)**

---

Please note that your example is not working because of:

```
SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE id = id -- always true
=> 
SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE id = _id (changed parameter name)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get_balance(_id text)
RETURNS json AS
$$
select '{"success" : false}'::json where not exists(select 1 from accounts where id = _id)
union all
select json_build_object('success', true, 'balance', balance) FROM accounts WHERE id = _id
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;
```